# Polynomials modulo $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Claim: For any polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients and any prime number $p$, there exists a polynomial $g(x)$ with integer coefficients such that $f(x^p) = f(x)^p + pg(x)$ or that $f(x^p) \equiv f(x)^p \mod p$.

My idea so far is if $f(x^p) \equiv f(x)^p \mod p$, then we're done.

So assume that $f(x^p) - f(x)^p \not \equiv 0 \mod p$.

Hence, $f(x^p) - f(x)^p \equiv y \mod p$ for some natural $y$ where $1 \leq y \leq p-1$.

Hence, $f(x^p) - f(x)^p - y = pt$ for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Hence, $f(x^p) = f(x)^p + y + pt$.

But from here I can't get seem to rewrite $y + pt$ in the form of $pg(x)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$. Perhaps my approach is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

First, we show $(a+b)^p\equiv a^p+b^p\pmod p$. By binomial theorem we get
$$
(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p+\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\binom pka^kb^{p-k}.
$$
Since $p\nmid k!$ for $k<p$ but $p\mid p!$, the claim is true.

Now let's do induction to prove $f(x)^p\equiv f(x^p)\pmod p$. For $\deg(f)=0$ the statement is true, because $f(x)^p = f(x^p)$.
Now let $m:=\deg(f)>0$ with the leading coefficent $a\neq 0$. We have
$$f(x)^p=(ax^m+g(x))^p\equiv (ax^{m})^{p}+g(x)^p\equiv (ax^{m})^{p}+g(x^p)=f(x^p)\pmod p.$$
We used that $\deg(g)<m$ for the induction step.